# Android List wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am creating some `TextView`, `ImageView`, `HtmlView` dynamically and adding it in following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_space"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_bar"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/quiz_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/quizView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/answer_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/quiz_scroll_viewTwo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/quizViewTwo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/answer_layoutTwo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

In `QuizView` I am adding some question related views at runtime, and for answers I am creating one list view runtime and adding to `answer_layout`. I am using `BaseAdapter` to create `ListView` runtime based on situation.

But my `ListView` is not showing all content, its showing only first cell.

I have adding `ListView` like this.

```
ListView ansList = new ListView(Test.this);
ansList.setAdapter(adapter);
ansList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ansCellLayout.addView(ansList);
```

it display only one list cell.

if I set some `int` value for height then its show all list contains.

```
ansList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 600));
```

But I cant Hardcode list view height as my contant is dynamic.

How to make list view as a `WRAP_CONTENT` in this scenario ?

Comment: Try with the solution I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Android developers as seen in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) Google I/O 2010 video , the ListView's height cannot be set to wrap_content. And when it is , the first three child elements are considered for the height. The others are simply not included.

Try setting the ListView's height at runtime. Or even better set it to FILL_PARENT.

Comment: Yes I have tried with FILL_PARENT but it dosent work, I ma trying to set height runtime.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation a `ListView` is

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list

So it's not supposed to be used with `WRAP_CONTENT` but rather to have a fixed height and scroll content inside it.

You'd better use a vertical `LinearLayout` for that purpose.

Comment: I have used LinearLayout but problem with it is, i am adding different views at runtime like text view, Web view etc. I have faced lots of issue with webview like setting up Webview height, and i need to use two different listener onclick for textview , ontoch for webview, multiple web view schooling, so I choose listview, its solves lots of issues like scrolling,listener etc.

Comment: do you want the list to be scrollable or to wrap the content ?

Comment: I want list view jsut display all his cells, at present its showing only one cell, if I set the height then its showing all cells, instead of setting height, it show take hight from his content. so I was using  wrap the content

Comment: which means you don't need any scrolling on your list, right ?

Comment: Yes, I dont need any scrolling for list.

Comment: then you should consider using a vertical `LinearLayout`, instead of a `ListView`